# Amplify+react: hosted ui with federated identity provider

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I would like to use the hosted ui with amplify in react.
The authentication should be done using federated identity provider, which is working correctly.
But I don't know, how to write the react part.
I found in amplify tutorial: that is should be possible with this sample:

```
// OAuthButton.js
import { withOAuth } from 'aws-amplify-react';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class OAuthButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.props.OAuthSignIn}>
        Sign in with provider's account
      </button>
    )
  }
}

export default withOAuth(OAuthButton);

// App.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import OAuthButton from './OAuthButton';
import Amplify, { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports'; // your Amplify configuration

// your Cognito Hosted UI configuration
const oauth = {
  domain: 'your_cognito_domain',
  scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
  redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
  responseType: 'code' // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
};

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
Auth.configure({ oauth });

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.signOut = this.signOut.bind(this);
    // let the Hub module listen on Auth events
    Hub.listen('auth', (data) => {
        switch (data.payload.event) {
            case 'signIn':
                this.setState({authState: 'signedIn', authData: data.payload.data});
                break;
            case 'signIn_failure':
                this.setState({authState: 'signIn', authData: null, authError: data.payload.data});
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
    this.state = {
      authState: 'loading',
      authData: null,
      authError: null
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('on component mount');
    // check the current user when the App component is loaded
    Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser().then(user => {
      console.log(user);
      this.setState({authState: 'signedIn'});
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      this.setState({authState: 'signIn'});
    });
  }

  signOut() {
    Auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.setState({authState: 'signIn'});
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { authState } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {authState === 'loading' && (<div>loading...</div>)}
        {authState === 'signIn' && <OAuthButton/>}
        {authState === 'signedIn' && <button onClick={this.signOut}>Sign out</button>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

In this form it is not working.
QA: 
how it should looks like the OAuthSignIn method?
Because when I used the window.open method to redirect to the hosted ui url, my react app doesn't know that the user was authenticated, how the code should looks like, that the app could recognize that the login flow was finished successfully?